# Achar os múltiplos fulgaps

Tags: c++, loop, if, for, lógica

O objetivo do programa é mostrar somente os números *fulgaps* de 0 a 999, número esse que deve ser divisível pela concatenação do primeiro e último número Ex: 192 / 12 ou 583 / 53.

Na compilação é mostrado todos os números de 1 a 999 e não somente os números desejados. Alguém pode me indicar qual o erro da minha lógica?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int Number{ 1 };
    int FirstLastNumber = ((Number / 100) * 10) + Number % 10;
    int Result = Number % FirstLastNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        if (Result == 0)
        {
            std::cout << Number << std::endl;
            Number++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você entende que a resposta que você aceitou não faz o que está no enunciado da pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa refazer a conta do `Result` para cada nova execução de `for`. Da maneira que é feito atualmente isso não ocorre, nessa situação você obtêm somente uma vez um valor para `Result`.

```c
int FirstLastNumber = ((Number / 100) * 10) + Number % 10;
```

Nessa linha você precisa diferenciar se o número é de 3 dígitos ou somente 2, pois o calculo é diferente. Sendo ele de 3 dígitos o calculo do resto no final da equação deve ser `Number%100` e não `Number%10` como está atualmente.

Segue um exemplo de 100 a 999 com base no seu código:

```c
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int Number{ 100 };
    int FirstLastNumber;
    int Result;

    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        FirstLastNumber = ((Number / 100) * 10) + ((Number % 100) % 10);
        Result = Number % FirstLastNumber;
        if (Result == 0)
        {
            std::cout << Number << std::endl;
        }
        Number++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é meio ambíguo. E o código tem muitas coisas sem sentido. O principal erro é fazer o cálculo fora do laço.

Nada foi dito sobre o que fazer quando o número tem apenas 2 dígitos e não 1. Vou considerar que o primeiro é 0. Então calculo apenas o último dígito nesses casos.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int FirstLastNumber;
        if (i < 100) FirstLastNumber = i % 10;
        else FirstLastNumber = ((i / 100) * 10) + i % 10;
        if (FirstLastNumber == 0 || i % FirstLastNumber == 0) std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wS82ot). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Fulgapscpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Fulgaps.cpp).

Comment: Muito obrigado, me atentarei mais a estes detalhes e tentar ser mais específico na próxima.